# CKEditor is undefined

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ckeditor

I've added [CKEditor.Net](http://ckeditor.com/download) to my ASP.NET web application project. When I try to insert text using javascript it gives this error

```
Error: 'CKEDITOR' is undefined
```

This is my code,

**HTML**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"    CodeBehind="Test.aspx.cs" Inherits="eLetters.Test" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="CKEditor.NET" Namespace="CKEditor.NET" TagPrefix="CKEditor" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function insertText(text) {
            CKEDITOR.instances.insertText('text');
        }
    </script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="FeaturedContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="CKEditor1" BasePath="/ckeditor/" runat="server"></CKEditor:CKEditorControl>
</asp:Content>
```

**C#**

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "MyKey", "insertText('data');", true);
    }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Set the default content?

Comment: @MikeSmithDev What I need to do is, insert some text from button click to CKEditor : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15018700/insert-text-to-ckeditor-programtically

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `BasePath="~/ckeditor"` in your markup.

Here's a code-behind snippet to instantiate the toolbar:

```
CKEditor1.config.toolbar = new object[] 
{ 
    new object[] { "Bold", "Italic", "Underline", "Strike", "-", "Cut", 
    "Copy", "Paste", "PasteText", "-", "NumberedList", "BulletedList", 
    "-", "Outdent", "Indent", "Blockquote", "-", "JustifyLeft", 
    "JustifyCenter", "JustifyRight", "JustifyBlock"} };
```

Comment out your text insertion script and just get it set up to begin ;-)

Comment: Actually CKEditor works fine in my project but when I try to insert text from javascript it gives the error...

Comment: @Nalaka526 you're correct but your Javascript is in the wrong place and has nothing to do with inserting at a particular index.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev I moved javascript calling  code from `PageLoad` to `ButtonClick` so it has a cursor location to insert text. To where do I have to move javascript?